# filter ForeignKey(user) model based on certain group_name

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

In Django i have created a model which use USER model data
this holds all user id form database, BUT i it filtered by certain group

> userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

[model.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Zlk.png)

```
**from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Review(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    reviewText = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):#for python <2
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):#for python 3
        return self.name**
```

[form displayed(with all user_id)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8gYa.png)

Comment: Please don't put code screenshots, put the code right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter foreign key choices, you can use `limit_choices_to` in your model field like this:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'Your Group Name'}, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```